# plsql cursor insert into different schemas

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I have 2 tables.
The first table contains pupils of many classrooms
 (name, age, classroom)

Another table contains schemas for each classrom (classroom, schema_name)

(So there are fo each classrom different schemas)

So I have different schemas for each classrom. I need to fetch all the data from pupils table and copied them into the target table of the correct schema. (I am logged as admin, I have access to all schemas)

here is my statement:

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR all_pupils
   IS
      SELECT NAME, AGE, CLASSROOM FROM TABLE_1
BEGIN
   FOR pupil_rec 
   IN  all_pupils
   LOOP
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' 
           || (Select schema_name FROM TABLE_2 sn WHERE sn.classroom=pupil_rec.CLASSROOM) ||'.TARGET_TABLE ' 
         ||'(name, age) VALUES (pupil_rec.name, pupil_rec.age';
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I am getting this error:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:
```

I just started learning PLSQL and I was told that I had to do it with the cursor. Can someone help me and tell me if this is the right approach? My structure seems not correct..how to avoid these errors

Comment: You can't just drop a `(select ...)` in the middle of any line you like. You need to expand your cursor to include the value you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` works with static strings only. So you need to query the schema name first, into a variable, then include that variable in your statement.

Also the contents of the cursor will not be in scope of the executed string. So you need to pass its values through placeholders.

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR all_pupils
    IS
        SELECT NAME, AGE, CLASSROOM FROM TABLE_1;
    l_schema_name varchar2(30);
BEGIN
   FOR pupil_rec 
   IN  all_pupils
   LOOP
       Select schema_name 
       into l_schema_name 
       FROM TABLE_2 sn 
       WHERE sn.classroom=pupil_rec.CLASSROOM:
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' 
           || l_schema_name  ||'.TARGET_TABLE ' 
           ||'(name, age) VALUES (:1, :2)'
           using pupil_rec.name, pupil_rec.age;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Alternatively, use a join in the driving cursor ...

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR all_pupils
    IS
        SELECT t1.NAME, t1.AGE, sn.schema_name  
        FROM TABLE_1 t1
             join TABLE_2 sn 
             on sn.classroom = T1.CLASSROOM
        where t1.col_copied != 1
        for update of t1.col_copied ;
BEGIN
   FOR pupil_rec 
   IN  all_pupils
   LOOP
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' 
           || pupil_rec.schema_name  ||'.TARGET_TABLE ' 
           ||'(name, age) VALUES (:1, :2)'
           using pupil_rec.name, pupil_rec.age;

       update  TABLE_1 t1
       set t1.col_copied = 1
       where current of all_pupils;

   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: I have an additional requirement (sry just found out now). My Table_1 has an additonal column (COL_COPIED). I need to set it to 1 when the row is selected and copied in the correct schema..so when the statement gets executed again it only select the rows that are not copied (TABLE_1 will always get new data). Can I just execute in my for loop an additonal statement (like the insert) that does the update? Or are there better solutions

Comment: thx very much, just a question (I am trying to understand your statement)
Your join at the beginning selects all data from table_1 like your first solution (without joins). You just used a join in order to refere to the schema_name inside the loop right?

Comment: yes. generally speaking, joining two tables is better than look-ups in a loop because set operations are more efficient than row-by-row processing. It probably doesn't make a lot of difference in your situation but it's never too early to get into good habits

Comment: I am getting an error at the line "where current of" it says missing '('.
And this line shouldnt end with a semicolon right: '(name, age) VALUES (:1, :2)'; ?

Comment: Hmmm, not sure why you get *that* error message: you must have made a typo. If you had translated my example correctly you would have got `pls-00413` because I had referenced the record variable not the cursor name (since corrected).

Comment: But this line: "using pupil_rec.name, pupil_rec.age;" should not have a semicolon at the end right? (trying to narrow down my mistake)

Comment: There was a rogue semicolon in my code. This is the problem with trying to write code without a sample schema to test it on 8-|

Answer (score -1):

A new variable will be required for saving the schema name. within `Execute Immediate` there cannot be concatenation of other `SELECT` unless its provided as a string.

```
DECLARE

    CURSOR all_pupils
    IS

        SELECT NAME,
            AGE,
            CLASSROOM
        FROM TABLE_1;

    v_chr_schema TABLE_2.schema_name%TYPE;
BEGIN

    FOR pupil_rec IN all_pupils
    LOOP

        SELECT schema_name
        INTO v_chr_schema
        FROM TABLE_2
        WHERE sn.classroom=pupil_rec.CLASSROOM;

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ' || v_chr_schema ||'.TARGET_TABLE ' ||
        '(name, age) VALUES (' || pupil_rec.name || ',' || pupil_rec.age || ')';

    END LOOP;

END;
/
```

Comment: thx very much, I changed my statement according your input but I am getting the error: 00984. 00000 -  "column not allowed here.

Comment: @Norbert94 - The values from cursor should have been outside of the string. Fixed now in the answer